# Samba password expires automatically

Tags: password, samba

I have a problem with samba, I have a user and a password for that user, and from a windows machine it let's me log in but after a day if I try to log in again and it tells me that the password is wrong; so I reset the same password in the server and it works again; and also at that time that samba folder is not accessible from any other PC as well.
 So this is not windows PC specific issue.

Any ideas what might be going wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Did you put some kind on expiration date or validity for unix users on your servers?